# cron job error : "sqoop command not found"

Tags: cron, sqoop

After installing sqoop successfully, i wrote a script "sqoop.sh" and kept in another folder. In terminal, I am able to execute sqoop script by giving command `./sqoop.sh`. It works fine. Now when i try to add a cronjob of this, error message "sqoop command not found".

Here is sample -

```
45 * * * * /home/user/Desktop/hadoop/sqoop/sqoop_script/sqoop.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the location of Sqoop's `bin` directory to the `PATH`. For example, when using `bash` shell, you can add these lines to the `.bash_profile`.

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Hi, bashrc file is already updated with SQOOP_HOME and PATH. When i am @ terminal -> user@abc:~$ sqoop help   it works fine. its just when i put the command in sqoop script and script is saved at different location, i am getting this error. It seems like either i have to change my script file location or i need to make some changes in crontab file.

Comment: You can try editing crontab file and setting the path in it. `crontab -e`, and then, add `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/bin` to top of file (edit the location to include Sqoop's `bin` directory).

Comment: Thnx it worked finally. I just added path whatever i added in Bashrc for SQOOP and JAVA home + PATH. It worked all fine.